# Is there a better way to check for strings from an input?

Tags: python

Im making a simple coordinate based movement system in python and the movement detection just looks really inefficient. This is what i have right now:

```
mvmt = str(input("Where do you want to move? "))
if mvmt == "w":
    zpos += 1
elif mvmt == "a"
    xpos -= 1
elif mvmt == "d":
    xpos += 1
elif mvmt == "s":
    zpos -= 1
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What kind of solution would you like?

Comment: "better" is releative, easier to read? Better to maintain? Better performance? ...

Comment: Depending on your level of sophistication and ambition, maybe look into using a dict for the keys, and/or a class for the object which you are moving.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class which store the position and update it, like this:

```
class Position:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dct = {'w': (1, 0), 's': (-1, 0), 'd': (0, 1), 'a': (0, -1)}
        self.pos = (0, 0)

    def new_position(self, mvmt):
        self.pos = tuple(map(sum, zip(self.pos, self.dct[mvmt])))
        return self.pos


pos = Position()

print(pos.new_position('a'))
# (0, -1)

print(pos.new_position('w'))
# (1, -1)

print(pos.new_position('w'))
# (2, -1)

print(pos.new_position('s'))
# (1, -1)
```

Comment: You've missed that there are 2 variables - zpos and xpos

Comment: OP wants to modify two different variables: `zpos` and `xpos`

Comment: @Alan you are right, I felt a bit ashamed to miss that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Wombatz you are right, updated the answer.